# VBA Code to point to BoxSync

Tags: vba

I have a program that I need to run, which I have written it in VBA.

Currently I am pointing to folders in C: drive and our A drive.

This is all being structured and i need to run of Box Sync, this is however user account based.

Could anyone give me any pointers how to go about using Box Sync to point to?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this assigning variable to Environ("USERPROFILE") + hardocoding rest of the link.